# Google Tag Manager not firing on link click in site footer?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

This is my first post - I have searched for the answer in other questions but couldn't find anything so hoping that someone can help with this specific question?

I'm trying to track a link that's sat in a 'floating' bar in the footer of [this site](http://www.ongo.co.uk/news/2016/05/home-ownership-team-scoops-top-honouragain/):

The link is #browsealoud - which is when you click on Screen reader - which upon clicking opens a pop-up which then reads out text (to assist those with sight problems).

I have set up the Tag and Trigger in Google Tag Manager, and know it works fine as when I insert the below link code in the body content, the Event is tracked in Google Analytics.

However, as this link sits in the floating grey bar in the footer, the trigger doesn't fire and I can't quite work out why. What is the best solution to allow me to track link clicks on this particular link (which appears on all pages)?

```
<a href="#browsealoud" onclick="browsealoud.toggleBar(); return false;" class="dark-arrow" data-bapdf="80"><h6>Screen reader</h6></a>
```

UPDATE: Screenshot of tag, trigger and variables below, as requested.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3FJu.jpg)

Comment: Can you please post screenshots of your GTM tag, trigger, and variables used? This will help us with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me as though you've already fixed this, as I think I can see a GA event firing whenever I click.

In any case, I think your problem is likely that there are two different places that you can click to obtain the same result; the text 'Screen reader' is actually a child of the element that includes the arrow, so clicking it will obtain a different set of attributes.

I woudl set up a custom javascript variable Parent href that reads the href of the parent of the clicked object. For example...:

```
function() {
return {{Click Element}}.parentElement.href;
}
```

And then set up a trigger that fires when either Click URL or Parent href is equal to #browsealoud.

Comment: There is a GA event firing (Link Click Listener), but it's not the one I have set up, which is called BrowseAloud :) Have added screenshots to the original post

Comment: In this blog they are explaining step by step how to use javascript custom variables: https://analyticsbar.com/blog/easy-tracking-click-events-with-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the screenshots. I believe what you need to do is to simply enable the History listener variables

[image]

The reason is because you are trying to track a URL fragment (ie. it has a hash) which GA doesn't track by default but can be tracked through GTM via the history listeners. I would also change your trigger to this:

[image]